# How to compile uBlox BLE android code on Github?

Tags: android, github, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have written an Android App that sends and receives BLE data from Phone(Client) to NINA B1-uBlox ( Peripheral). The App is working but I do get a lot of data loss and have to request the same data again. I found code on GitHub of how to send and receive BLE data.
I want to load the code on my phone end enter debug mode, to see what they do to connect to the SPS service on the NINA B1.

When I compile the code from GitHub, I receive a lot of errors and run down a rabbit hole to try and fix the errors.

Did someone successfully compile this code? : https://github.com/u-blox/Android-u-blox-BLE
[enter link description here](https://github.com/u-blox/Android-u-blox-BLE)

Comment: So how did you manage to build it? https://github.com/u-blox/Android-u-blox-BLE/issues/7#issuecomment-1003610665 mentions "following advice given to another user.", which is not exactly helpful. You can post a detailed answer below (to your own question), and accept your own answer.